# SUSE Linux 12 - configuring IP alias

Tags: linux, suse

I want to setup an IP address alias on a Network card. I created a file /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-ens160:0 and file contents are

```
BOOTPROTO=static
STARTMODE=onboot
IPADDR=192.168.0.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

Contents of file /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-ens160 are

```
BOOTPROTO=static
STARTMODE=onboot
IPADDR=192.168.0.0
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR_1=192.168.0.1
NETMASK_1=255.255.255.0
LABEL_1=ENS160:0
```

I restart the network by running  systemctl restart network.service

and then run command /sbin/ipconfig -a, but I do not get both the IP address in results. I am not sure how to configure this.

Answer (score 0):

You have filenames mixed up. If you use labels, you can just put everything into one file, namely the file which configures the main interface.

For example, put the following into `/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-ens160` to get interfaces `ens160` and `ens160:foo`:

```
BOOTPROTO=static
STARTMODE=onboot
IPADDR=192.168.0.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR_1=192.168.0.1
NETMASK_1=255.255.255.0
LABEL_1=foo
```

As a side note, this question should be in [superuser](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead of SO as it's not a programming question.

Comment: Hi Sami, I followed your suggestions, but still I do not see the ip alias in ifconfig -a. Ihave posted question in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119592/suse-linux-12-configuring-ip-alias